# Formatting a date string to be suitable for Google calendar as argument

Tags: javascript, date, google-visualization, google-calendar-api

I have a string that represent a data like 2014-July-2014. I am formatting this date in javacript so that I can use it as an argument for Google calendar chart.

E.g.

```
var x = "2014-July-12";

var splitted = x.spilt('-');
// to get "2014" at index [0], "July" at index [1] and "12" at index [2].
```

I then use a key value array to get the months in number.
Then I populate Google calendar data table with..

```
data.addRow([new Date(ParseInt("splitted[0]"),months.splitted[1], ParseInt("splitted[2]")), dataValues[i].Value]);
```

I use ParseInt() to convert from string to numbers since new Date(yyy,mm,dd) taks only integers as arguments.
I cannot get this calendar working. I searched a lot on the net but cannot find a good example of how to populate Google calendar calendar chart from json file.

Can you guys take a look and guide me how to do this task and explain were i'm wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Draw Calendar Chart Function

```
function drawCalendarChart(jsonObj) {

    var dataValues = eval(jsonObj)
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
       data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Reports' });

       for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {

           var date = new Date(dataValues[i].Date);
           var year = date.getFullYear(), month = (date.getMonth() + 1), day = date.getDate();
           if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
           if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
           var Formatted = "" + year + "," + month + "," + day;
           //           data.addRow([new Date(dataValues[i].Date), dataValues[i].Frequencies]);
           data.addRow([new Date(Formatted), dataValues[i].Frequencies]);
       }
       var options = {
         title: "Calendar Chart",
         height: 350
       };
       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('chart'));

       chart.draw(data, options);
       var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
       table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
   }
```

I added the function i'm using to draw the chart. The data is giving a NaN,NaN error. The frequency is getting the right values. So it must be related to date formatting.
This is the test string i'm using.

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-10",
        "Frequencies": 11
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what kind of data are you trying to display? Cause by this post, it is confusing, you said that you need a Google Calendar parameter, but the code you provide is for the `Google DataTables`, which is for statistics and surveys... you could provide also your json data in order to make it easier to help you.

Comment: I have a json file like this `[
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    }
]` I want to use Google Calendar Chart to display this information. I cannot add these row entries manually. I need to use a loop to populate the rows. I this method for other Charts e.g. Pie Chart etc and worked fine. The problem is with the dates since it is not in the correct format required by the addRow function and cannot get it work.

Comment: Try my updated answer and give some feedback pls.

Comment: I will try after 20:00 since I'm at work and update everyone. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Keep it simple***, this should work:

```
data.addRow([ new Date(dataValues[i].Date), dataValues[i].Frequencies ]);
```

**UPDATE**

**It worked for me**, here you have a working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kutyel/p75eqmun/5/)** with the code.

Comment: I tried this. The chart is being drawn at least the Title but the dates are giving a NaN, NaN. I know since I am also showing the data table under the calendar chart. This is the sample data I am using [
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-10",
        "Frequencies": 11
    }
]

Comment: @user2307236 check updated answer, solved your problem in provided fiddle. Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem is that the date is returned in this format from the file `/Date(12712000000)/`. I solved this issue with few lines of code. `for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
      
       var formatted = new Date(parseInt(dataValues[i].Date.substr(6)));
   
        var jsDate = new Date(formatted); //Date object
        data.addRow([ new Date(jsDate.getFullYear(), jsDate.getMonth(),jsDate.getDate()), dataValues[i].Frequencies ]);
       }` Thank You all for your help

Comment: I'm glad you found what you need, hope to have helped. Are you rewarding me the bounty then?

Comment: Yes of course. I accepted your answer. Do I need to do something else to reward you the bounty, since it is the first time and I'm not sure if I rewarded you with the bounty.

Comment: I think you must do something else cause the bounty is not yet rewarded :S

Comment: @user2307236 I believe there is some kind of "reward bounty" button beside each answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can convert your string date values to numbered date.

```
var date = new Date("12-January-2014");
var year = date.getFullYear(), month = (date.getMonth() + 1), day = date.getDate();
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

var Formatted = "" + year+"," + month+"," + day;
```

**EDIT**

```
  var vt=  new Date(year, month, day);

  alert(vt);
```

Now you can use this variables in data function as needed.

Here is [code](http://jsfiddle.net/hmahida/cp67yv66/)

Hope it helps..!!!

Comment: Even this is not plotting the calendar due to incorrect date. I added the function to draw the charts + test data

Comment: You do not have to write "Formatted" in new date , just create new date with year,month and date as variable shown above.

Comment: Your solution is absolutely not worth it, your first line: `var date = new Date("12-January-2014");` is already a valid javascript date, so there is no need to do all the stuff that follows.

Comment: @Kutyel yes you are right, but User wanted it to convert in "NUMBERS" look in question "I use ParseInt() to convert from string to numbers since new Date(yyy,mm,dd) takes only integers as arguments"